# How to make TCPS/SSL connection to Oracle using C#

Tags: c#, oracle

Need to connect to oracle from C# using OledbConnection class.
This connection needs to be secure/SSL/TCPS enabled.
I appreciate if anyone can provide solution for this in C#.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: For SQL Server, this is easy: include `encrypt=true` in the connection string.

Comment: For SQL Server, you can do that on the server with no client changes. Just provision a cert (unless you use a less secure self-signed one) and turn on force encryption using SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Did you check the documentation? Have you tried something? Have you setup encryption on the *server's side*? C# has nothing to do with this - you only need to set the appropriate keyword in the connection string for each product

Comment: Yeah as mentioned by Jeroen I am able to connect to the SQl Server but I am having issue with Oracle 12c connectivity.

Comment: For Oracle I am using a connectionstring having tns like format with port 2484 and protocol as TCPS but getting error ORA-28759: failure to open file

Comment: @Panagiotis : I have created certificate using orapki and imported in cacerts using keytool provided by java. If in my oracle connectionstring if I keep 1521 i.e. tcp port and tcp protocol the tns like format connectionstring is working.Issue is with only TCPS protocol

Comment: Update your question and use the *appropriate* tags. If you don't have a problem with SQL Server, don't use the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Updated question as for SQL Server I am having solution as mentioned by  Jeroen and Dan

Comment: Anybody has answer for How to make TCPS/SSL connection to Oracle using C#?